# Difference between binding a method and not

Tags: reactjs

I've been into a several React projects now, and I've notice in one project that every new method is not binded. What is the actual difference (if there's any)? Why bind if you could do it like the second example?

In the first case, the code has looked like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { myState: false };
  this.clickMe = this.clickMe.bind(this);
}

clickMe() {
  this.setState({ myState: !this.state.myState });
}
```

The other example looks like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { myState: false };
}

clickMe = () => {
  this.setState({
    myState: !this.state.myState
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `constructure`,

```
this.clickMe = this.clickMe.bind(this);
```

Using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method you do explicit `this` binding to provide context to `clickMe` method.

ie. React Component Scope here

In short,you taking care to decide what is the invoking context scope (`this` binding).

But with

```
clickMe = () => {
  this.setState({
    myState: !this.state.myState
  });
}
```

[`Arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) take care for you do lexical scope binding of the React Component scope within which it is define.No need to use `bind`

If you dont use `arrow function`,without `bind`,your function will not get `bind`ed to React Component scope.

Answer (score 2):

Arrow functions are great because they are faster and easier to write. In a small or medium size app there's not a tangible difference. You can use the arrow functions if you prefer and avoid the binding inside the constructor.

However, someone has decided to look at performance and side effects. So you can check these 2 links:

1. [When Should I User Arrow Functions?](https://reactarmory.com/answers/when-to-use-arrow-functions)
2. [Arrow Functions in Class Properties Might Not Be As Great As We Think](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1)