# React Js axios set state and self not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the code I've written so far to get data using axios.

What am I doing wrong?

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    user_list: []
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios
    .get("http://192.168.1.35:3012/user_list", {})
    .then(function(response) {
      var datalist = response.data[0];
      this.state({ user_list: response.data });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native setState not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098867/react-native-setstate-not-a-function)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189438/difference-between-binding-a-method-and-not/51189571#51189571  check this one

Answer (score 1):

The function given to `then` after your axios request doesn't have the `this` value you expect.

You could e.g. make it into an arrow function to make it work:

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios
    .get("http://192.168.1.35:3012/user_list")
    .then((response) => {
      var datalist = response.data[0];
      this.state({ user_list: response.data });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```